# missing first row from csv

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am reading a .csv file into a dataframe (CorpActionsDf), but when I print the head of the CorpActionsDf I see that I'm missing the first row of data:

head of .cvs data:

```
BBG.XAMS.ASML.S 24/04/2015  0.7 Annual  Regular Cash
BBG.XAMS.ASML.S 25/04/2014  0.61    Annual  Regular Cash
BBG.XAMS.ASML.S 26/04/2013  0.53    Annual  Regular Cash
BBG.XAMS.ASML.S 26/11/2012  9.18    None    Return of Capital
BBG.XAMS.ASML.S 27/04/2012  0.46    Annual  Regular Cash
```

head of CorpActionsDf:

```
                       date  factor_value reference             factor
unique_id                                                             
BBG.XAMS.ASML.S  25/04/2014          0.61    Annual       Regular Cash
BBG.XAMS.ASML.S  26/04/2013          0.53    Annual       Regular Cash
BBG.XAMS.ASML.S  26/11/2012          9.18      None  Return of Capital
BBG.XAMS.ASML.S  27/04/2012          0.46    Annual       Regular Cash
BBG.XAMS.ASML.S  26/04/2011          0.40    Annual       Regular Cash
```

As you can see the first row of data in the csv is missing from the dataframe.

```
BBG.XAMS.ASML.S 24/04/2015  0.7 Annual  Regular Cash
```

My code is as follows:

```
def getCorpActionsData(rawStaticDataPath):
    pattern = 'CorporateActions'+ '.csv'
    staticPath = rawStaticDataPath

    with open(staticPath+pattern,'rt') as f:

        #staticDf=pd.read_csv(f,engine='c',header=0,index_col=0, parse_dates=True, infer_datetime_format=True,usecols=(0,3))
        CorpActionsDf=pd.read_csv(f,engine='c',header=0,index_col=0, parse_dates=True, infer_datetime_format=True,names=['unique_id', 'date','factor_value','reference','factor'])        
        print('CorpActionsDf')
        print(CorpActionsDf.head())
```

Any one have an idea what I'm missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried header=None instead of header=0?

Docu says for header=0:

"Default behavior is as if set to 0 if no names passed, otherwise None. Explicitly pass header=0 to be able to replace existing names."

```
 CorpActionsDf=pd.read_csv(f,engine='c',header=None,index_col=0, parse_dates=True, infer_datetime_format=True,names=['unique_id', 'date','factor_value','reference','factor'])
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `None` instead of `0` for the `header` parameter. Otherwise you tell the code to treat the 0th row as the one containing the headers and only replace them later with the `names` parameter.

```
CorpActionsDf=pd.read_csv(f,engine='c',header=None,index_col=0, parse_dates=True, infer_datetime_format=True,names=['unique_id', 'date','factor_value','reference','factor'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you are using parameters well. I don't know pandas because I use Numpy but if I look the [Pandas Documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), I assume that header and names parameters are not good.

`header = 0` replaces existing names, so you should write `header = None`.

```
CorpActionsDf=pd.read_csv(f,engine='c',header=None,index_col=0, parse_dates=True, infer_datetime_format=True,names=['unique_id', 'date','factor_value','reference','factor'])
```

Try and say me if it's better or not ? Otherwise, you can use Numpy and I could help you !